# ios 8 background service ends after 15 to 20 mins

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, background

IOS 8 stops background call after 15 min.

I am using background service to send gps to service every 2 mins. app sending data properly for 15 min after that its stops sending data. this happens only in ipad mini, in rest of ipad its working fine, data going properly eben for 8 hours.

iOS 8 background service ends after 15 to 20 mins. I am testing in iPad mini, but its working fine in normal iPad, I had enabled background app refresh, and everything fine. but its not working after 20 min, but same code working fine in other device except iPad  mini, I am using iPad mini cellular ? kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for this is an app crash.  I had it happen when my background refresh ran over the allowed 30 seconds.  Then the app appears to still be running when you reactivate it, but in fact it's restarted.

Check the device logs and see if you've had crashes like this.  Given the date, you probably already solved your problem.

Also remember that iOS calls for BG refresh when it wants, and it's very idiosyncratic.